# Dominated Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Is there a function that dominates

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^nx^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

on $(1,\infty)$ for all $n$? I need to apply DCT to get $e^{-x}$.Obviously MCT doesn't apply since $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing but $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is increasing to $e^x$. The best I got was $\frac{1}{1+x}$ but it's not in $L^1$.

Comment: @DrMV Where did your answer go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have for $x\in[1,\infty)$

$$x^{-1/n}\le 1 \tag 1$$

Next, we show that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is increasing function of $n$ for $x>0$.  To that end, we analyze the ratio

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac x{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n}&=\left(\frac{n(n+1+x)}{(n+1)(n+x)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac xn\right)\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{x}{(n+1)(n+x)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac xn\right) \tag 2\\\\
&\ge \left(1-\frac{x}{n+x}\right)\left(1+\frac xn\right) \tag 3\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

where we used Bernoulli's Inequality to go from $(2)$ to $(3)$.  We have shown that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is increasing in $n$.  Therefore, we can assert for $n\ge 2$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n}&\le \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1+x+\frac14x^2}\tag 4
\end{align}$$

Putting all of this together, we have from $(1)$ and $(4)$

$$\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^nx^{1/n}}\le \frac{1}{1+x+\frac14 x^2}$$

Inasmuch as the integral of the dominating function satisfies the condition

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x+\frac14 x^2}\,dx<\infty$$

then by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^nx^{1/n}}\,dx&=\int_1^{\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^nx^{1/n}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get the first inequality?

Comment: Interesting... I've never seen that way of writing the functions that converge to $e^x$

Comment: Yes, but as an increasing sequence, not as the rhs

Comment: How does it go to $e^x$?

Comment: What was wrong with the original answer?

Comment: While it is true that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ <e<\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$, $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\ <e^x$, and that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ $ increases to $e$ while $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ decreases to $e$, it is not true in general that $e^x\le \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n+1}$.  So, egg on my face for writing such a ridiculous inequality since here $x\ge 1$ and not $0\le x\le 1$.

Answer (score 3):

When $n \geq 2$, notice that for $x > 0$ we have

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n = 1 + x + \frac{n-1}{2n}x^2 + \cdots \geq 1 + x + \frac{1}{4}x^2. $$

Using this we can bound $(f_n)$ on $(1, \infty)$ for $n \geq 2$ by

$$ f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{1+x+x^2/4}. $$

Comment: Are you allowed to just throw away the first term like that? how about finitely many?

Comment: But I mean you just aren't dominating the first term

Comment: @user284963, Oh, now I understood your question. If $(f_n)$ are integrable and $\varphi \in L^1$ dominates $(f_N, f_{N+1}, \cdots )$, then the following function $$ |f_1| + \cdots + |f_{N-1}| + \varphi $$ is integrable and dominates the whole sequence. So that is not a serious issue.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is not integrable, and integrals are linear so how then is that + what you have integrable..

Comment: @user284963, In your problem, $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)x}$ is integrable.