# $(1+x/n)^{1/n}$ monotone increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $\{x_n\}=(1+1/n)^n$, by using Bernoulli's inequality, $(1+a)^n>1+{na}$, and a little creative, clever algebra, it is a straightforward proof to show that $x_{n+1}/x_n>1$ and hence $\{x_n\}$ is a monotone increasing sequence. I thought that the same approach (the ratio of consecutive elements) and the same basic set of algebraic constructions might be used to show that $\{x_n\}=(1+x/n)^n$ for $x>0$ is also a monotone increasing sequence but it's escaping me, I'm afraid. I've seen other solutions that refer to the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality but I'd like to attempt a more basic solution that doesn't refer to that. Any hints to push me in the right direction?

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1502853/42969 is a proof using Bernoulli.

Comment: Are you interested in $(1+x/n)^{1/n}$ or $(1+x/n)^n$?

Comment: The latter, $(1+x/n)^n$